# Boost.Python - ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_example)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost

I am trying to compile the module https://github.com/Auctoris/boost_python_impex using the command line.

The following command builds and links the module .so file successfully:

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m library.cpp example.cpp -c
g++ -L /lib64 -shared example.o -o example.so -lpython3.6m -lboost_python3
```

However, when I import the module from python3 I get the following error message:

```
  import example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_example)
```

I don't understand this error message, as the library.cpp file contains the line:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
```

and I am importing the module from **Python3**.

What is wrong/missing with my compilation command?

I am using Fedora 64bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following compilation command works on Fedora 29:

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m library.cpp example.cpp -shared -o example.so -lboost_python3
```